# Resume option similar to enumitem package for paralist package

Tags: enumerate, counters

I would like to know if it is possible to generate a `resume` option similar to that in the `enumitem` package for the paralist package. Note that it is not possible to add something like `[resume]` or `[start]` to the environments defined in the `paralist` package. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum}{2}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedenum}\\[1cm]
Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum}{1}
    \item Some long text to be used for sampling.
\end{tabbedenum}\\[1cm]
Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item text 
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text 
\end{tabbedenum}
\bigskip
Some long text to be used for sampling.
\NumTabs{3}
\begin{inparaenum}
\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text
\tab\item text   
\end{inparaenum}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After a quick look into `paralist` docs - no (edit: that is, not without modifying `paralist`'s macros).   But current versions of `enumitem` support so-called "inline" enumerations, i.e., enumerations within a paragraph.

Comment: @mbork Could you provide a mwe illustrating the above output with desired outcome in the resume enumeration.

Comment: Yes, but not before a few hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add code that remembers the value of the counter at the end of `tabbedenum` and define a new environment `tabbedenum*` that uses the previous value:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newenvironment{tabbedenum}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}}
 {\xdef\lastparaenum{\the\value{enumi}}\endinparaenum}
\newenvironment{tabbedenum*}[1]
 {\NumTabs{#1}\inparaenum\let\latexitem\item
  \def\item{\def\item{\tab\latexitem}\latexitem}%
  \setcounter{enumi}{\lastparaenum}}
 {\xdef\lastparaenum{\the\value{enumi}}\endinparaenum}
\def\lastparaenum{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum}{2}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\end{tabbedenum}

Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum*}{1}
    \item Some long text to be used for sampling.
\end{tabbedenum*}

\bigskip

Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum*}{3}
\item text 
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text 
\end{tabbedenum*}

\bigskip

Some long text to be used for sampling.
\begin{tabbedenum}{3}
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text
\item text   
\end{tabbedenum}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that using `tabbedenum` resets the numbering.